# Getting a Future from a Vector and a function

Tags: rust, async-await

I'm pretty new to Rust and to it's async/await model, and I'm trying to do something that looks like a specialized Haskell's `traverse` function. Given a `Vec<T>` and a function `T -> Future<Output = R>` I want to get a `Future<Output = Vec<R>>`.

At the moment, I have the following:

```
use futures::{FutureExt, StreamExt};

pub async fn traverse<I, T, R, F, FN>(xs: I, f: FN) -> Vec<R>
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    F: FutureExt<Output = R>,
    FN: Fn(T) -> F,
{   
    futures::stream::iter(xs)
        .fold(vec![], |acc, item| {
            f(item).map(move |app| {
                let mut a = acc;
                a.push(app);

                a
            })
        })
        .await
}
```

It works as expected, but doesn't feel very idiomatic. Does anybody has suggestion how to improve this function?

Comment: I've edited the title, but I don't see any error in the question. That being said, the above `traverse` function is a generalized way to transform a Vec of Future to a Future of Vec. you can get back the expected behaviour by passing the vector of Future as first argument and the second argument must be the identity function `|x| x`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best is to simply use [`then()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.then) and [`collect()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.collect):

```rust
use futures::{Future, StreamExt};

pub async fn traverse<I, T, F, Fut, O>(xs: I, f: F) -> Vec<O>
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    F: Fn(T) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = O>,
{
    futures::stream::iter(xs).then(f).collect().await
}
```

Note:

- futures generic should be name `Fut`
- function generic should be name `F`
- I rename `R` as `O` but I don't know if it's better but it's my way.
- Doesn't need `FutureExt`